# the meaning of 'times': multiplication or addition/subtraction

Tags: meaning-in-context

Judy can jump rope 50 times.
Bill can jump rope 150 times.
He can jump rope 3 times more than Judy does.

In the last sentence, 'times' means 'multiplication'.
I wonder if this following sentence is possible :

He can jump rope 100 times(150-50) more than Judy does.

Comment: *Times* has multiple possible meanings. In your example, it is ambiguous, and is more likely to be interpreted as multiplication (300 vs. 3). If you want subtraction, rephrase *... 100 more times than ...*

Comment: For reference (in theory)"3 times more" means 1 time +3 times so x4", whereas "3 times as many" means x3. Although you'll unfortunately often hear 3 times more used to describe x3.

Comment: Thanks, bib and MorganFR. Your explanations help me grasp what it means.

Answer (score 2):

There are two meanings of ‘times’ in your example sentences:
'Times’ meaning ‘occasions’ and 
‘Times’ expressing multiplication. 
You tell us that in ‘He can jump rope 3 times more than Judy does’, ‘times’ it is intended an expression of multiplication. 
In ‘He can jump rope 100 times(150-50) more than Judy does’ it denotes occasions of the action.
However, without your having given us the information as to the absolute number of jumps Bill and Judy are each capable of completing, we may well have interpreted the first example as denoting ‘occasions of the action’ and concluded that Bill was capable of jumping rope only 53 times.
I would suggest that for clarity, when using times to express multiplication, you try a construction like ‘He can do three times as many rope jumps as Judy can’.